# WPF Custom Navigation Buttons and calling one page from another

Tags: wpf, user-interface, navigation

I have a window which contains a Frame which references a 'home' page that has buttons on it.  When a button is clicked I want another page to show depending on which button was pressed.  I attempted to use

`NavigationService.Navigate('mynextpage.xaml')`

and that works however, I want to use a customized navigation panel.  I call

`this.ShowsNavigationUI = false;`

on my 'home' page but the bar still shows.  Is there a way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

My page with the frame is a window so I do not know how to disable the Navigation bar there where I guess it is coming from.

Further testing shows that the ShowsNavigationUI property is false yet the nav bar shows itself in the parent window once there is a second page to go to (showing the 'home' page in the history.

TIA

Comment: sounds like this should work.  did you make sure that ShowsNavigationUI is a property and is raising the PropertyChanged event from INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: I am not sure I follow or how to do that.  showNavigationUI shows up in my intellisense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if i understand you correctly you want to hide the navigation chrome of a Frame, to do so set

```
<Frame Name="hostFrame" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"/>
```